# rsync does not have permissions to be triggered by php

Tags: php, rsync

I'm trying to sync two local folders by triggering rsync from a php script. The following error is produced:

```
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/Library/xxxxxxx" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

How do I give php/apache permissions to trigger the rsync process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have permissions to create directory.

Use `chown` on directory `/Library` and assign to the same user that is executing **Apache** server, and give permission of 755 to all files and directories, for example, if the user executing **Apache** is **daemon**:

```
sudo chown daemon.daemon -R /Library
sudo chmod 755 -R /Library
```

Comment: Thanks @Sal00m, I ended up using this solution, though Adder's was also workable. On OS X the user is _www.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache/PHP process usually does its work as user www-data.
To allow user www-data to write to a directory, you could manually change owner or group to www-data, and give write permission to the directory for either user or group. This however might break other processes which work with the directory.

```
chgrp www-data /Library && chmod g+a /Library
```

If you will rsync multiple times, i.e. when the directory already exists:

```
chgrp -R www-data /Library/directory && chmod -R g+a /Library/directory
```

Another approach would be to use a setuid script.
This is a script which is called by user www-data but executes as the owner of the script. But that might be a security problem.

http://www.krenel.org/setuid-and-shell-scripts-explained/